# dt.Alamat error CS0103: The name 'dt' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LatihanMenu
{
    class ProdanceRent :TempData
    {
        MainMenu MM = new MainMenu();
        List<> data; //= new List<>();
        public ProdanceRent()
        {
            data = new List<>();
        }
        public void inputMember()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Silahkan Input Data Member");
            Console.WriteLine("Nama depan Member\t= ");
            NamaDepan = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Nama Belakang member\t= ");
            NamaBelakang = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ID Member\t= ");
            IDMember = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Alamat Member\t= ");
            Alamat = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Telepon Member\t= ");
            NoTelepon = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Tanggal Gabung member\t= ");
            TanggalBergabung = Console.ReadLine();
            MainMenu MM = new MainMenu(NamaDepan, NamaBelakang, Alamat, IDMember, NoTelepon, TanggalBergabung);
            data.Add(MM);
        }

        public void tampilkanMember()
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data Tidak ada");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var dt in data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.NamaDepan+", "+dt.IDMember+" dengan alamat di "+dt.Alamat+" dan Nomer Telepon "+dt.NoTelepon+" Bergabung dengan prodase Rent Car pada tahun "+dt.TanggalBergabung);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its an untyped list, try `List<MainMenu> data = new List<MainMenu>();`

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, please do not add to the OP question with format... You added code that was not there before...

Comment: Once you have assigned the List it won't ever equal null, you need to check `data.Count == 0` rather than `data == null`

Comment: Setelah Anda menetapkan Daftar itu tidak akan pernah sama dengan nol, Anda perlu memeriksa `data.Count == 0` dari pada `data == null`